# JVM crashed randomly

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

We have deployed Spring base web-application on tomcat-6 with Java-1.7. It is crashing abruptly after new deployment. There are no specific pattern.

Error Log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fda9a04344f, pid=3012, tid=140575487555328
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_95-b14) (build 1.7.0_95-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.95-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0xf44f]  _tr_stored_block+0x13f
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x00007fda64009000):  JavaThread "http-8080-exec-5" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3383, stack(0x00007fda47eff000,0x00007fda48000000)]

    siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr=0x00007fda70565000

    Registers:
    RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0xffffffffffff4e90, RCX=0x00007fda70554680, RDX=0x0000000000010981
    RSP=0x00007fda47ffc690, RBP=0x00007fda47ffc690, RSI=0x0000000000010980, RDI=0x00007fda70548df8
    R8 =0x00007fda70109e50, R9 =0x00007fdb7052d30c, R10=0x00007fda7053847c, R11=0x00000006c2ac8118
    R12=0x00007fda7053847c, R13=0x00007fda70109e50, R14=0x0000000000000200, R15=0x0000000000000000
    RIP=0x00007fda9a04344f, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010293, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
      TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fda47ffc690)
    0x00007fda47ffc690:   00007fda47ffc6d0 00007fda9a043d77
    0x00007fda47ffc6a0:   00007fda64009000 00007fda70109e50
    0x00007fda47ffc6b0:   000000000000fffb 0000000000000000
    0x00007fda47ffc6c0:   0000000000000200 00000000ffffffff
    0x00007fda47ffc6d0:   00007fda47ffc700 00007fda9a03bdbd
    0x00007fda47ffc6e0:   00007fda70095770 00007fda70095770
    0x00007fda47ffc6f0:   00007fda70109e50 0000000000000000
    0x00007fda47ffc700:   00007fda47ffc740 00007fda9a03c026
    0x00007fda47ffc710:   01007fda47ffc740 00007fda640091e8
    0x00007fda47ffc720:   00000006c2ac8140 00007fda47ffc7c8
    0x00007fda47ffc730:   0000000000000000 00007fda70095770
    0x00007fda47ffc740:   00007fda47ffc7b0 00007fda9a036c89
    0x00007fda47ffc750:   0000000000000200 00007fda47ffc7d8
    0x00007fda47ffc760:   00007fda70090c90 000000011e6e9288
    0x00007fda47ffc770:   e3f134d400000000 0000000723dc1298
    0x00007fda47ffc780:   00000006c2ac8380 00007fda47ffc860
    0x00007fda47ffc790:   0000000000000000 0000000000000001
    0x00007fda47ffc7a0:   0000000000000000 00007fda64009000
    0x00007fda47ffc7b0:   00007fda47ffc800 00007fda8c0029ad
    0x00007fda47ffc7c0:   0000000000000000 00000006c2ac80a8
    0x00007fda47ffc7d0:   0000000000000001 00000006c2ac8130
    0x00007fda47ffc7e0:   00007fda70109e50 00007fda64009000
    0x00007fda47ffc7f0:   00000000e47b8253 00007fda8bb5dde0
    0x00007fda47ffc800:   0000000000000000 00007fda8bce07bc
    0x00007fda47ffc810:   00000006c2ac8118 00000007241cee28
    0x00007fda47ffc820:   0000000000000200 0000000000000200
    0x00007fda47ffc830:   00000006c2ac80a8 00000007241cee10
    0x00007fda47ffc840:   00007fda47ffc8a0 00000006c2ac8130
    0x00007fda47ffc850:   00007fdad8559023 0000000000000000
    0x00007fda47ffc860:   0000000000000001 00007fda9b44cf17
    0x00007fda47ffc870:   00000000d8559015 00007fda8bfb3bd0
    0x00007fda47ffc880:   00000006c2ac8130 0000000600000200 

    Instructions: (pc=0x00007fda9a04344f)
    0x00007fda9a04342f:   d7 4d 8d 4c 02 01 0f 1f 00 41 8b 50 28 0f b6 07
    0x00007fda9a04343f:   48 83 c7 01 49 8b 48 10 89 d6 83 c2 01 4c 39 cf
    0x00007fda9a04344f:   88 04 31 41 89 50 28 75 e0 c9 c3 66 0f 1f 44 00
    0x00007fda9a04345f:   00 85 c0 0f 8e 5f ff ff ff 41 8b 50 28 41 0f b7 

    Register to memory mapping:

    RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    RBX=0xffffffffffff4e90 is an unknown value
    RCX=0x00007fda70554680 is an unknown value
    RDX=0x0000000000010981 is an unknown value
    RSP=0x00007fda47ffc690 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fda64009000
    RBP=0x00007fda47ffc690 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fda64009000
    RSI=0x0000000000010980 is an unknown value
    RDI=0x00007fda70548df8 is an unknown value
    R8 =0x00007fda70109e50 is an unknown value
    R9 =0x00007fdb7052d30c is an unknown value
    R10=0x00007fda7053847c is an unknown value
    R11=
    [error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb]

    Stack: [0x00007fda47eff000,0x00007fda48000000],  sp=0x00007fda47ffc690,  free space=1013k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    C  [libzip.so+0xf44f]  _tr_stored_block+0x13f
    C  [libzip.so+0xfd77]  _tr_flush_block+0x117
    C  [libzip.so+0x7dbd]  deflate_stored+0x18d
    C  [libzip.so+0x8026]  deflate+0x1d6
    C  [libzip.so+0x2c89]  Java_java_util_zip_Deflater_deflateBytes+0x269
    J 5394  java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(J[BIII)I (0 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c0029ad [0x00007fda8c0028e0+0xcd]

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    J 5394  java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(J[BIII)I (0 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c002933 [0x00007fda8c0028e0+0x53]
    J 5393 C2 java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate([BIII)I (140 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8bce07bc [0x00007fda8bce06a0+0x11c]
    J 3778 C2 java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write([BII)V (88 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8bfb3bd0 [0x00007fda8bfb38a0+0x330]
    J 5450 C2 java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write([BII)V (18 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c3ba314 [0x00007fda8c3ba280+0x94]
    J 5477 C2 org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.FlushableGZIPOutputStream.flushLastByte()V (27 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c4051a8 [0x00007fda8c405140+0x68]
    j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.FlushableGZIPOutputStream.flush()V+26
    j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.flush()V+32
    J 6394 C2 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (1127 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c98655c [0x00007fda8c9854c0+0x109c]
    J 7006 C2 org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(Z)V (109 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8ca6fe34 [0x00007fda8ca6fbc0+0x274]
    j  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush()V+2
    j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.flush()V+12
    j  org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flush()V+15
    j  org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter;Z)V+13
    j  org.apache.jsp.jsp.taskviewlist_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;)Z+142
    j  org.apache.jsp.jsp.taskviewlist_jsp._jspService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+355
    j  org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+44
    j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+81
    j  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Z)V+315
    j  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;Z)V+126
    j  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+347
    j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+81
    J 6457 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (670 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c9bcac0 [0x00007fda8c9bc8e0+0x1e0]
    J 6458 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (105 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c3feb20 [0x00007fda8c3feae0+0x40]
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Lorg/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher$State;)V+393
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Lorg/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher$State;)V+64
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+339
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+55
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+243
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+84
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+222
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExecutionChain;Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView;Ljava/lang/Exception;)V+115
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+929
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+373
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+71
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+35
    j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+53
    j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+83
    j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+81
    J 6457 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (670 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c9bcac0 [0x00007fda8c9bc8e0+0x1e0]
    J 6458 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (105 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c3feb20 [0x00007fda8c3feae0+0x40]
    j  org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+53
    j  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+111
    J 6457 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (670 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c9bcc00 [0x00007fda8c9bc8e0+0x320]
    J 6458 C2 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (105 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c3feb20 [0x00007fda8c3feae0+0x40]
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+804
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+365
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+64
    j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
    J 4235 C2 org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (700 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c1793c0 [0x00007fda8c1783e0+0xfe0]
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+42
    j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+185
    J 5306 C2 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioChannel;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (904 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c55aeb0 [0x00007fda8c55aae0+0x3d0]
    j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioChannel;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;+129
    j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V+123
    J 4691% C2 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V (225 bytes) @ 0x00007fda8c300e50 [0x00007fda8c300c20+0x230]
    j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+19
    j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x00007fda84059800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(79)-10.100.41.115" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14901, stack(0x00007fda55772000,0x00007fda55873000)]
      0x00007fda84059000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(78)-10.100.41.115" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14900, stack(0x00007fda571ce000,0x00007fda572cf000)]
      0x00007fda64146000 JavaThread "AD Thread Pool-Global24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14555, stack(0x00007fda572cf000,0x00007fda573d0000)]
      0x00007fda8406e800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(19)-10.100.41.115" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5582, stack(0x00007fda458ba000,0x00007fda459bb000)]
      0x00007fda680ab000 JavaThread "AD Thread Pool-CGG0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3494, stack(0x00007fda573d0000,0x00007fda574d1000)]
      0x00007fda680af800 JavaThread "AD Thread Pool-Coalescable_CS_Scheduler0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3493, stack(0x00007fda56fcc000,0x00007fda570cd000)]
      0x00007fda7430a800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3434, stack(0x00007fda45abc000,0x00007fda45bbd000)]
      0x00007fda7430a000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3433, stack(0x00007fda55d20000,0x00007fda55e21000)]
      0x00007fda7429b800 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3432, stack(0x00007fda56023000,0x00007fda56124000)]
      0x00007fda742cb000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3428, stack(0x00007fda45bbd000,0x00007fda45cbe000)]
      0x00007fda74275800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3427, stack(0x00007fda45cbe000,0x00007fda45dbf000)]
      0x00007fda74273000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3426, stack(0x00007fda45dbf000,0x00007fda45ec0000)]
      0x00007fda74271800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3425, stack(0x00007fda45ec0000,0x00007fda45fc1000)]
      0x00007fda74283000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3424, stack(0x00007fda45fc1000,0x00007fda460c2000)]
      0x00007fda74281000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3423, stack(0x00007fda460c2000,0x00007fda461c3000)]
      0x00007fda74280000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3422, stack(0x00007fda461c3000,0x00007fda462c4000)]
      0x00007fda74296800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3421, stack(0x00007fda464c6000,0x00007fda465c7000)]
      0x00007fda74295800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3420, stack(0x00007fda463c5000,0x00007fda464c6000)]
      0x00007fda74284000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3419, stack(0x00007fda465c7000,0x00007fda466c8000)]
      0x00007fda7427d800 JavaThread "Timer-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3418, stack(0x00007fda462c4000,0x00007fda463c5000)]
      0x00007fda4804f000 JavaThread "AD Thread-Hotspot Processor0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3409, stack(0x00007fda466c8000,0x00007fda467c9000)]
      0x00007fda958e1800 JavaThread "Timer-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3408, stack(0x00007fda467c9000,0x00007fda468ca000)]
      0x00007fda4c133800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3407, stack(0x00007fda468ca000,0x00007fda469cb000)]
      0x00007fda4c131000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3406, stack(0x00007fda469cb000,0x00007fda46acc000)]
      0x00007fda4c12f000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3405, stack(0x00007fda46acc000,0x00007fda46bcd000)]
      0x00007fda4c12d000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3404, stack(0x00007fda46bcd000,0x00007fda46cce000)]
      0x00007fda4c12b000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3403, stack(0x00007fda46cce000,0x00007fda46dcf000)]
      0x00007fda4c129800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3402, stack(0x00007fda46dcf000,0x00007fda46ed0000)]
      0x00007fda4c125800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3401, stack(0x00007fda46ed0000,0x00007fda46fd1000)]
      0x00007fda4c124000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3400, stack(0x00007fda46fd1000,0x00007fda470d2000)]
      0x00007fda4c122800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3399, stack(0x00007fda470d2000,0x00007fda471d3000)]
      0x00007fda4c121800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3398, stack(0x00007fda471d3000,0x00007fda472d4000)]
      0x00007fda4c128000 JavaThread "Timer-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3397, stack(0x00007fda55c1f000,0x00007fda55d20000)]
      0x00007fda5011a000 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3392, stack(0x00007fda472d4000,0x00007fda473d5000)]
      0x00007fda84032800 JavaThread "AD Thread-Top Backends Processor0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3391, stack(0x00007fda473d5000,0x00007fda474d6000)]
      0x00007fda5801a800 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3390, stack(0x00007fda477f8000,0x00007fda478f9000)]
      0x00007fda58018000 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3389, stack(0x00007fda478f9000,0x00007fda479fa000)]
      0x00007fda58016000 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3388, stack(0x00007fda479fa000,0x00007fda47afb000)]
      0x00007fda58014800 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3387, stack(0x00007fda47afb000,0x00007fda47bfc000)]
      0x00007fda5800f800 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3386, stack(0x00007fda47bfc000,0x00007fda47cfd000)]
      0x00007fda5800d000 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3385, stack(0x00007fda47cfd000,0x00007fda47dfe000)]
      0x00007fda58012800 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3384, stack(0x00007fda47dfe000,0x00007fda47eff000)]
    =>0x00007fda64009000 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-5" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3383, stack(0x00007fda47eff000,0x00007fda48000000)]
      0x00007fda6401f000 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3382, stack(0x00007fda5401a000,0x00007fda5411b000)]
      0x00007fda6401d000 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3381, stack(0x00007fda5411b000,0x00007fda5421c000)]
      0x00007fda6401c000 JavaThread "http-8080-exec-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3380, stack(0x00007fda5421c000,0x00007fda5431d000)]
      0x00007fda96347800 JavaThread "http-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3379, stack(0x00007fda5431d000,0x00007fda5441e000)]
      0x00007fda96162800 JavaThread "http-8080-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3378, stack(0x00007fda5441e000,0x00007fda5451f000)]
      0x00007fda9618d000 JavaThread "http-8080-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3377, stack(0x00007fda5451f000,0x00007fda54620000)]
      0x00007fda94227000 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3376, stack(0x00007fda54620000,0x00007fda54721000)]
      0x00007fda96345800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3375, stack(0x00007fda54721000,0x00007fda54822000)]
      0x00007fda94f5f000 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3374, stack(0x00007fda54822000,0x00007fda54923000)]
      0x00007fda9603a800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3339, stack(0x00007fda54923000,0x00007fda54a24000)]
      0x00007fda957c6800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3338, stack(0x00007fda54a24000,0x00007fda54b25000)]
      0x00007fda95fbf800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3337, stack(0x00007fda559ad000,0x00007fda55aae000)]
      0x00007fda9578c000 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3336, stack(0x00007fda55b1e000,0x00007fda55c1f000)]
      0x00007fda9553c800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3282, stack(0x00007fda5526d000,0x00007fda5536e000)]
      0x00007fda95553000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3281, stack(0x00007fda5536e000,0x00007fda5546f000)]
      0x00007fda9534b800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3280, stack(0x00007fda5546f000,0x00007fda55570000)]
      0x00007fda9554a000 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3279, stack(0x00007fda55570000,0x00007fda55671000)]
      0x00007fda64004000 JavaThread "JMX server connection timeout 45" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3170, stack(0x00007fda55671000,0x00007fda55772000)]
      0x00007fda4c00b000 JavaThread "RMI RenewClean-[10.100.41.115:1091]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3166, stack(0x00007fda55e21000,0x00007fda55f22000)]
      0x00007fda947bb000 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3165, stack(0x00007fda55f22000,0x00007fda56023000)]
      0x00007fda947b8000 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3163, stack(0x00007fda56124000,0x00007fda56225000)]
      0x00007fda947a6800 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=3162, stack(0x00007fda56225000,0x00007fda56326000)]
      0x00007fda947a5000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1091" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3161, stack(0x00007fda56326000,0x00007fda56427000)]
      0x00007fda947b2000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1090" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3160, stack(0x00007fda56427000,0x00007fda56528000)]
      0x00007fda94756000 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3159, stack(0x00007fda56528000,0x00007fda56629000)]
      0x00007fda944e0800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3122, stack(0x00007fda56ecb000,0x00007fda56fcc000)]
      0x00007fda94423000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3116, stack(0x00007fda574d1000,0x00007fda575d2000)]
      0x00007fda94350800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3115, stack(0x00007fda575d2000,0x00007fda576d3000)]
      0x00007fda9434f800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3043, stack(0x00007fda578d5000,0x00007fda579d6000)]
      0x00007fda5c355800 JavaThread "Thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3040, stack(0x00007fda800fe000,0x00007fda801ff000)]
      0x00007fda94119800 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3029, stack(0x00007fda8056c000,0x00007fda8066d000)]
      0x00007fda94116000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3028, stack(0x00007fda8066e000,0x00007fda8076f000)]
      0x00007fda94108000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3027, stack(0x00007fda88473000,0x00007fda88574000)]
      0x00007fda94106000 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3026, stack(0x00007fda88574000,0x00007fda88675000)]
      0x00007fda940e6000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3025, stack(0x00007fda88675000,0x00007fda88776000)]
      0x00007fda940e4000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3024, stack(0x00007fda88776000,0x00007fda88877000)]
      0x00007fda9400c000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3014, stack(0x00007fda9ad0a000,0x00007fda9ae0b000)]

[_thread_blocked, id=3114, stack(0x00007fda801ff000,0x00007fda80300000)]
      0x00007fda5c3c3000 JavaThread "AD Thread-Metric Reporter1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3045, stack(0x00007fda576d3000,0x00007fda577d4000)]
      0x00007fda5c3c4800 JavaThread "AD Thread-Metric Reporter0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3044, stack(0x00007fda577d4000,0x00007fda578d5000)]
      0x00007fda5c3a5000 JavaThread "AD Thread-Config Poller" daemon
```

Please help us to identify root cause from crash-log. We are not be able to re-produce it locally.

Comment: It seems occured while unzipping. Can you tell us what is your environment and more about your application ?

Comment: Also, can you take thread dumps, they will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not necessarily a good answer, but I have some hints to share, that did not fit in a comment:

Stack trace says server is handling an HTTP GET request on a jsp page, and error occurs while *compressing* (deflate=compress, inflate=uncompress) output (the http response).

Compression is delegated to the native libzip library. You could add JVM argument `-Xcheck:jni` to get more details if something is unclean regarding native calls.

Maybe one/some of your jars is/are modified at runtime: that kind of shenanigans can trigger bugs like the one you are experiencing. I'm really not sure about that one, because your error occurs while zipping an http response, but maybe if at the same time the lib is used to read a jar that was altered in an unexpected way, mayyybe then... (so a full thread dump could probably help but I don't know if you can obtain one upon JVM crash). Anyway, you could use option `-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true` to [circumvent this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=190481), or find the root cause (what causes jars to be altered at runtime) and fix that (again, assuming it's the problem).

Comment: thanks but can you please explain how a jar can be modified at runtime.

Comment: That would be accidental, and entirely dependent on your setup. Might happen if someone or a script messes with your installation. I've seen that with bad auto-update scripts for example.